# listof Command Malfunctioning - float Package

Tags: floats, captions

Consider the following code for the creation of two new floats in an article:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,float}
% The First Float Type
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\newfloat{BoxImage}{htpb}{csv}[section] 
\floatname{BoxImage}{Boxed Image}
% The Second Float Type
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{FloatEqn}{htpb}{csv}[section]
\floatname{FloatEqn}{Float Equation}

\begin{document}
    \listof{BoxImage}{List of Boxed Images}
    \listof{FloatEqn}{List of Floating Equations} 
    \section{New Float Types}
    \begin{BoxImage}
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{This is an image with the new float.}
    \end{BoxImage}
    \begin{FloatEqn}
        \[ E = mc^2 \]
        \caption{Mass-Energy Equivalence.}
    \end{FloatEqn}
\end{document}
```

the problem is with the list of objects it appears like this:

---

[image]

---

The list of the second object is behaving in an odd way, and I don't know why. So, if you can help I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide a small but complete test file that makes the output shown, you have posed two fragments but there is no documenclass and it is much better to post a sigle complete example.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question now.

Comment: actually I see it just need \documntclass{article} and changing `image` to `example-image` then it shows he probelm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the same toc file (`csv` here you can't hav independent lists, the ouput is a little odd and I didn't trace what it is doing but you can use two exensions, csv and csw say and get

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
% The First Float Type
\floatstyle{boxed} 
\newfloat{BoxImage}{htpb}{csv}[section] 
\floatname{BoxImage}{Boxed Image}
% The Second Float Type
\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{FloatEqn}{htpb}{csw}[section]
\floatname{FloatEqn}{Float Equation}

\begin{document}
    \listof{BoxImage}{List of Boxed Images}

    \listof{FloatEqn}{List of Floating Equations} 

    \section{New Float Types}
    \begin{BoxImage}
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{This is an image with the new float.}
    \end{BoxImage}
    \begin{FloatEqn}
        \[ E = mc^2 \]
        \caption{Mass-Energy Equivalence.}
    \end{FloatEqn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried it and it worked.